# Is a question on distributing a test application really a good "known good" audit?

Tags: discussion, review-audits

How are audit questions chosen?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21355024/how-to-send-your-apk-glass-application-for-your-client-to-see)  was in the 'Reopen' queue as an audit question. It clearly deals with the distribution of software but is implicitly asking for a third-party or external link option. Is this truly a good candidate for reopening?

Comment: This is possibly a duplicate of [How Are Review Audit Posts Selected](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189000/how-are-review-audit-posts-selected). And I think the reason that it wasn't closed at all was because it wasn't _explicitly_ asking for a third-party solution, and to me, that would open the door for coded solutions.

Comment: Where is it asking for a third party/external link or product recommendation?  I don't see that in the question.

Answer (score 11):

Not every question to which a tool recommendation could be an answer is a recommendation question. In actual fact the OP does what I'd wish more users would to where it concerns their recommendation questions.

The question is entirely problem focused. *"How can I put the Glassware (apk) up online so he can "load it up" into his glass remotely? Or deploy it to his glass?"* If there is a programmatic solution, great. If there is something in the SDK, wonderful. If there is an external tool, fine.

The question here is not "what tool do you recommend to do X?" but "How do I solve this problem I'm facing?". It's perhaps a subtle shift, but it's an important one. I'd say that makes the question acceptable, and the audit fine.

Afaik the audits are automatically chosen, based on the community's evaluation of a question. With a score of +6, this is regarded as a good question, and an audit with it would expect that you evaluate it similarly.