# Good review audit has "possible spam" warning?

Tags: support, review, review-audits

I was looking through someone's edit history and I was looking at [this review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/3703217):

[image]

Why does it give this notice, while at the same time saying that it's a high-quality post?

Comment: [Review audits and spam notifications are completely unaware of each other](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/216787), so if something looks suspicious to the spam filter it will give you a message, despite the post being a known-good audit. However, in my experience, every time I come across this message, the review task turns out to be an audit. I suspect that the spam filter picked up some wrong signal because it is an audit, and involves a post that would normally not show up in the review queue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Precisely because it's an audit. The point is to see if the user is paying attention to the post itself, not robo-clicking to earn badges.

Comment: That'd only be useful during the review -- is there any purpose of that after reviewing?

Comment: Well, I think the "possible spam" or "is this post whatever" label is part of the audit itself, so it shows up even when you look at it in hindsight. It lets you see precisely what the reviewer saw at the time of the audit. An SE employee may have more insight into the reasoning.

Comment: Yes, @Qantas: to be less confusing when someone like you posts a link. This answer is correct, btw.

Answer (score 0):

It would have been marked automatically (through an **algorithm**) as being potential spam.

The quality mark would have been given by **human** intervention which spotted that it wasn't spam.

It is being used as a clear cut example of whether you would do the same and are paining attention and are acting more like a human than an algorithm* ;)

*knowing these are not entirely exclusive categorisations.

Comment: Note that posts for review audits are also selected by an algorithm: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189000/how-are-review-audit-posts-selected/189009#189009